# How to solve Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' error in vb.net but works in Workbench?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, delete-row

I am deleting the record using id of the record. When i execute this , it shows error as  "Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

```
 mod_sql.conn2.Open()
sd_cmd2 = String.Format("DELETE FROM risk where `id`='{0}';", nd_index)
cmdd_delete2 = New MySqlCommand(sd_cmd2, mod_sql.conn2)
 cmdd_delete2.ExecuteNonQuery()
 mod_sqlconnect2.conn2.Close()
```

I tried to change the Delete command to

```
 sd_cmd2 = String.Format("DELETE FROM risk where `id`={0};", nd_index)

 sd_cmd2 = String.Format("DELETE FROM risk where id={0};", nd_index)
```

Nothing worked. 
If i copy the same sql command and tried in MySQL Workbench, the record get deleted.

Comment: I don't know the VB SQL API, but you don't even need backticks around `id`.  So, you may try removing them.

Comment: is there any chance that you didn't USE the database you want? It would be a big coincidance to have `risk` table in 2 different databases, but maybe thats the problem. Thrown error seems to be very specific; seems to be connected to a database; table exists; so the table seems to look differently.

Comment: Another idea is case-sensitivity?

Comment: Also remove `;` at the end of your sql

Comment: Thanks Tunker. Actually Conn2 refers to another database having same table name and that table doesnt have 'id' column. Thanks for ur reply.